# How do I unzip a .zip file in a remote directory using NAnt ftp task?

Tags: nant, build-script, nant-task

I have a zip file in my ftp server. Is there any way to unzip it using NAnt?
Here is a sample code of what I would like to do:

```
<ftp connection="liveAuditToolConnection" remotedir="/remotedir">
  <unzip zipfile="backup.zip"/>
</ftp>
```

Suppose that the backup.zip file already exists in the ftp server.
thanx:)

Answer (score 0):

NAnt does not support remote operations. If you are running on a Windows system, trying looking at [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)